# border-bottom appears on top of the element

Tags: css, html

I can't figure out why my the bottom border won't appear below my navbar. It was working fine until I added #topheader so I figure that's my problem. If so, is there a more effective way to get the black box on top? hank you for any help

```
<header>
<div id="topheader">
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="logo">
    <h1>TheWay</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>


 <!--  Navigation Bar -->

 <div class="wrapper">

 <div id="nav_bar">

 <nav>

 <a href="home.html">Home</a> 

 <a href="blog.html">Blog</a> 

 <a href="music.html">Music</a> 

 <a href="events.html">Events</a> 

 <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
 </nav>
  </div>
</div>
 </header>
```

Here is the full code:
http://tinker.io/a31d6/2

Comment: Please always include relevant code within the question.

Comment: I see no `border-bottom` rules in your CSS.

Comment: I should of included the issue instead of explaining it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a border-bottom on your example at all, but assuming that you're adding it to #nav_bar, try also adding an overflow: hidden to your #nav_bar. Hopefully this will do what you want.

Comment: Kiwimind, THANK YOU! That did the trick. Can I ask you how you knew that would do the trick and why I had to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: If you've got floats inside an element (like you have inside your #nav_bar div), the floated elements are removed from the flow, so the div effectively has no size, which means that the border-bottom would appear near the top. When you add in an overflow: hidden, it ensures that the div wraps all the elements inside it, including floats. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think I understand. So once I add a float to an element, the "children" inside the element leave and the parent element ends up collapsing?

Comment: Yeah, effectively the parent element ends up having zero height if it only contains floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be problem with `float: left;`

```
#nav_bar nav a {
    /* ... */
    float: left;
    /* ... */
}
```

You can try replacing the float with `display: inline-block;`